# Not getting some items from the list

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following code for searching students ID from a list after adding a student. The first time I fetch for it, it works normally but when I add another student and search for that particular ID I don't find it. Can someone tell me where is the mistake?

```
public void AddMarks(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mystudent.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mystudent[i].Id == id)
        {
            foreach (Student st in mystudent)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("enter Mathematics halfyearly exam");
                 Maths.HYEXAM = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                 Console.WriteLine("enter Mathematics annualyear exam");
                 Maths.ANEXAM = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense: why are you traversing the list two times? And what's Maths, did you maybe mean st.Maths?

Comment: what did the debugger tell you

Answer (score 1):

Well look at your loop. It's not doing *anything* with the student... instead you're setting variables like this:

```
Maths.HYEXAM = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

That certainly *lookS* like you're setting a static variable. Are you? If so, you need to go back and revise what "static" means. Work out how the mark is meant to be associated with the specific student you're interested in.

Then work out why you've got *two* loops - why are you iterating over all the students with a `for` loop, then if you find a match, you're iterating over them all again with a `foreach` loop...